# Sublime Text Hotkey/Keybinding for Multiple Cursors on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/06/23/sublime-text-keyboard-shortcuts-cheat-sheet-win-os-x-and-linux#.U4SkQ5RdW8E

Both of those sites suggest that Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down will add another cursor.  But my Mac OS X seems to have some behavior already set to that.  It zooms all of the windows out or in depending on whether I use up or down.

Does anyone know a) how to disable this OS X functionality? or b) how to change the key binding for this in Sublime's "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap -User" file?

Happy trails!
-Pete

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I figured it out after reading this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3331893?tstart=0

Basically, I just had to disable "Mission Control" and "Application Windows" in System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts.

[image: Keyboard Shortcut preferences]

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I've been searching for a solution for this.

Answer (score 12):

Add these lines to Key Bindings-User in Sublime settings

> { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
>
> { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }

and you are good to go without changing anything in the preferences. now multicursors will work with

> ctrl+alt(option)+up/down

Answer (score 5):

You can use additional **fn** key to get pretty much the same key bindings usability: **fn** + **up** = **pageup** on mac.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+pageup"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+pagedown"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} }
```

I found it quite usable for myself and there is no need to disable "Mission Control" and "Application Windows" in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use Karabiner (https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner). It has a set of predefined examples but adding your own commands is a piece of cake. 
Easy to install and to use and to customize. 
Also available on github: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner.